# Building intranet search

Tags: search, intranet

At work, we have lots of information squirreled away in many different sites -- wikis, product docs, ticketing system, etc -- many of which require authentication.

I'm very interested in having a single way to search all our various silos, and in my spare time have looked at Nutch, Grub, Django + Haystack, etc.  None of these is a complete solution a la Google Mini or Google Search Appliance.

Has anybody built a basic intranet search engine out of a mixture of these tools?  Would you have recommendations about how to go about it?  I like Django, and Haystack seems to be a mildly popular search solution for it, but I'd need to wire up a crawler that can support crawling authenticated sites to it.

Comment: So ... why not buy a Google Search Appliance? Do you have a need for free-as-in-beer or free-as-in-speech? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

[Velocity by Vivisimo](http://vivisimo.com/solutions/oem.html) is a great product, but expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) from the Apache Foundation. Also take a look on their [PoweredBy](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/PoweredBy) wiki page, maybe you even find a project already using lucene.